# Trying to split words in string by space to become elements in array

Tags: php, string

I am trying to turn the words in a string into elements in an array by splitting the string with space (" ") as the delimiter.

I am trying to use explode, but after I `var_dump()` the array that explode is supposed to make, I see that the result is an array, but with weird values.

Here is my code:

```
/*

var_dump() of $matches is array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(72) "business bossiness busyness bushiness fussiness" [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(1) "9" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(47) "business bossiness busyness bushiness fussiness" } }

*/
$suggestionsString = $matches[0][0];
$suggestionsArray = explode(" ", $suggestionsString);
var_dump($suggestionsArray);
```

But the output I get from the `var_dump()` looks like:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
      [0]=>
       string(72) "<c o="0" l="9" s="1">business    bossiness   busyness    bushiness   fussiness</c>"
[1]=>
string(1) "0"
[2]=>
string(1) "9"
[3]=>
string(1) "1"
[4]=>
string(47) "business    bossiness   busyness    bushiness   fussiness"
  }
}
```

Why am I getting this output and how can I split the words in my string so each word is a word in an array?

What I am trying to get is just those 5 words in an array.

Comment: http://codepad.org/Fje4mpQF

That works good for me

Comment: There's no way your code exactly as above produces that output.  Verify that your `$suggestionString` actually contains what you think it does before you `explode()` it.

Comment: I ran exactly the code you have printed and I did not get that var dump at all.

Comment: Three people independently verified that your code ought to work as expected; this means that the code you are actually running is "in some way" not the code you just posted. Please check and get back to us.

Comment: By the way - I tried reformatting your "I get this output" to make it easier to read, and realize there may be characters missing from your output (for example, there is no element `[1]`, and the value of element `[0]` appears to be truncated after the opening `"`). Can you please check / fix?

Comment: @Floris I updated my question with my full code.

Comment: @jQuery00 I updated my question with my full code.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I updated my code with my full code. No truncations.

Comment: @xsearingheaven that is probably because I truncated my code. I now updated my question with all of my code.

Comment: @DjangoJohnson But the `var_dump($matches)` you posted above can't be right. It shows, for example, `[0][0]` as having string length 72 when it's actually 47.  View the _page source_ and copy/paste the dump from there so all the line breaks and indentation are intact, as well as any additional HTML characters which may be embedded in there.  I have a feeling you'll see a longer string than you expect...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I checked the source like you suggested and there are a bunch of spaces and line breaks. I updated my question with the output from the source.

Comment: @DjangoJohnson Looks like a `preg_match_all()` array, and the match you are interested in is `$matches[0][4]`, not `[0][0]`, which is the _entire input string_.  Then since you have multiple spaces, you'll need `preg_split('/\s+/', $str)` instead of plain `explode()`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Could you write that and in more detail as an answer so I can try it and mark it as correct if it works?

Comment: @DjangoJohnson Sure, coming right up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once we saw the original input array `$matches` in its entirety, it becomes much clearer what your issue is, and it stems from attempting to debug via `var_dump()` with a web browser rather than viewing the direct output PHP sends (visible in the page source).

Your input array `$matches` looks to be the result of a `preg_match()` call, and contains HTML or XML markup. (Hopefully you are not attempting to process XML via regular expressions - better to use a proper XML parsing library)

```
// Input array ($matches)
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
      [0]=>
        string(72) "<c o="0" l="9" s="1">business    bossiness   busyness    bushiness   fussiness</c>"
      [1]=>
        string(1) "0"
      [2]=>
        string(1) "9"
      [3]=>
       string(1) "1"
      [4]=>
       string(47) "business    bossiness   busyness    bushiness   fussiness"
  }
}
```

The first array element returned by `preg_match()` is the full matched string, *not* its inner matches from `()` capture groups, and that is what you attempted to match originally.  Instead, the value you need is `$matches[0][4]` which contains the correct inner match.

Since your word list is separated by *multiple* space characters rather than single spaces, you cannot use `explode()`.  Instead you need to use `preg_split()` with an expression like `\s+` to match one or more whitespace characters:

```
$suggestionsString = $matches[0][4]; // string(47) "business    bossiness   busyness    bushiness   fussiness"
$suggestionsArray = preg_split('/\s+/', $suggestionsString);
var_dump($suggestionsArray);

// Prints:
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  string(8) "business"
  [1] =>
  string(9) "bossiness"
  [2] =>
  string(8) "busyness"
  [3] =>
  string(9) "bushiness"
  [4] =>
  string(9) "fussiness"
}
```

Comment: +1... finally we are getting somewhere. Now that we know the question, we may know the answer!

Comment: This got me exactly what I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When I run the following script:

```
<?php
$suggestionsString = "business bossiness busyness bushiness fussiness";
$suggestionsArray = explode(" ", $suggestionsString);
var_dump($suggestionsArray);
?>
```

I get

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "business"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "bossiness"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "busyness"
  [3]=>
  string(9) "bushiness"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "fussiness"
}
```

exactly as expected. Somehow you are not doing what you think you are doing...

Answer (score 0):

there is no way that what you have posted can be really happening unless the post is a misrepresentation of your code

heres the deal --

```
<?php 
$suggestionsString = "business bossiness busyness bushiness fussiness";
$suggestionsArray = explode(" ", $suggestionsString);
var_dump($suggestionsArray);
?>
```

I ran this as is (no modification)
RESULT

*array(5) { [0]=> string(8) "business" [1]=> string(9) "bossiness" [2]=> string(8) "busyness" [3]=> string(9) "bushiness" [4]=> string(9) "fussiness" }*

the [] Tags represent the index of the arrays that are being returned.

*array(4) { [0]=> string(2) " string(5) "o="0"" [2]=> string(5) "l="9"" [3]=> string(57) "s="1">business bossiness busyness bushiness fussiness"* }

Your array states that there are 4 indexes available but your result is only showing [0] [2] [3]  ???  wheres [1]

What you wrote works

not sure why u get this broken dump ...

Answer (score -1):

Use print_r instead of var_dump if you only want the values and not the information about the values.

Comment: That isn't what's being asked here.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: I read the problem as "I am seeing things like 'string(2)' and I only want to see indexes and values". You obviously see a completely different problem.

Comment: Issue appears to be that the OP is getting unexpected output like `o="0"`  in the array, with all the space-separated values still intact as a string in key `[3]`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski If that is his problem, it is simply that he either isn't typing a space in " " or that his string is not delimited by spaces. There are many whitespace characters that look like spaces but are not ASCII 32.

Comment: @kainaw Or more likely, the input string contains HTML and when the var_dump is viewed in the browser, what appears looks like nonsense. Note my comment above about the string length of 72....